# Vim nested execute commands syntax

Tags: vim

I am trying execute a nested execute command within a vimscript. I know that this command works in ex mode:

```
g/\(^\n\|\%1l\).\_.\{-}\n$/execute "normal! vap:call MCformat()\<cr>"
```

I want to be able to run that command from within a script. I have tried a number of permutations of the following code but can't get it to work.

```
function! RunMCformat()   
  silent! execute "normal! g/\(^\n\|\%1l\).\_.\{-}\n$/execute \"normal! vap:call MCformat\(\)\<cr>\""

endfunction
```

Probably I am not escaping the string properly but I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the double quotes, you'd have to escape (i.e. double) the backslashes inside the `/.../` pattern definition. However, the biggest problem is the first `:normal!`; `:g[lobal]` is an *Ex command*. So, you're lucky, you can just prepend `:silent!` (which invokes Ex commands like `:global`), are you should be done; no nested `:execute` is necessary:

```
function! RunMCformat()   
    silent! global/\(^\n\|\%1l\).\_.\{-}\n$/execute "normal! vap:call MCformat()\<cr>"
endfunction
```

In general, I would avoid nesting of `:execute`; that's not readable in any case. Rather, extract parts of your code into a function / custom command (in which you can use `:execute`), and invoke that.